# Markov Process and a continuous PDF

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

I read an economics [paper](https://github.com/soyoung-lee-n/files/blob/master/earnings_soyoung.pdf), and I got quite confused about the setting of the model: they assume that the labor productivity $\varepsilon$ (defined on a discrete state space) follows a Markov process. In the simulation/calibration part, they specify their assumption further: the labor productivity is drawn from a bounded Pareto distribution with a fixed probability $\delta_{\varepsilon}$ that the labor productivity will get redrawn.

I know that there are three key elements for a discrete Markov process (from textbook definition): state space $S=\{\varepsilon_{1}, ..., \varepsilon_{n}\}$, transition matrix $P_{n\times n}$, and the initial probability $\pi_{0}=\begin{bmatrix}
P(X_{0}=\varepsilon_{1})\\ 
\vdots\\ 
P(X_{0}=\varepsilon_{n})
\end{bmatrix}$, where $X_{0}$ is drawn from some **discrete** distribution.

My questions are:

1. How could they draw the labor productivity from a **continuous** distribution (i.e., bounded Pareto distribution)?
2. How could they specify the transition matrix $P_{n\times n}$ and
   the initial probability $\pi_{0}$ in this case if allows assuming a
   fixed probability to get the labor productivity redrawn?

Comment: It would be helpful if you included a link to the paper you are referring to.

Comment: Sorry for that! The link for the paper is https://github.com/soyoung-lee-n/files/blob/master/earnings_soyoung.pdf

Comment: Without reading the paper, I would assume that the _type_ of labor productivity varies among a finite number of cases, with the labor productivity itself following a distribution depending on that (hidden?) type, $\epsilon$. This would be coherent with the parameter $\delta_\epsilon$ of the Pareto depending on $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

There is also theory about Markov Processes defined on continuous state spaces, you can google for that. Your definitions are for discrete state spaces, where everything's a little bit more straightforward.